# Restoring a Time Machine backup on Yosemite's clean install

Tags: time-machine, macos

If I want to perform a clean install of OS X Yosemite, can I restore my Mac with a Mavericks Time Machine backup after the Yosemite installer finishes?

Comment: Sorry if this might be a duplicate question, but I was unable to find something that answered this particular question.

Comment: Do you want to restore the OS or just your data?

Comment: Just the data and my preferences if possible.

Comment: There should be no problem doing that.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure I don't run into some message of sorts saying hey this time machine back up is from Mavericks and you can't restore it on Yosemite or something...

Comment: One would assume Apple has considered that the 10.9 and 10.10 are compatible :)

Comment: Can you select a speceific time to restore to?

Comment: I just completed a clean install of OS X Yosemite and plugged in my usb backup drive that had my system backed up from Mavericks. I can see the mounted disk on the desktop and can browse the files, but when trying to restore from the disk it says that no complete backup could be found. I did some searching and it looks like others are having a similar problem. Looks like I may have to manually fish out my files (music, photos, et cetera) from the drive instead of a 'one push button' approach.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring an entire Time Machine backup is certainly possible after cleanly installing Yosemite. Just boot to the Recovery HD and choose restore from backup.